# Error in Struts2 ParametersInterceptor

Tags: java, struts2, setter, mutators, struts-action

> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor error
>       SEVERE: Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
>   
>    Unexpected Exception caught setting 'Screen_name' on 'class org.ScreenCreation: Error setting expression 'Screen_name' with value ['kjn', ]

I'm new with struts2 and I have this error, can any one help me to solve it ?

Comment: For the record: Haven't marked it as a duplicate. Maybe it is, but not a dup of the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

> Unexpected Exception caught setting 'Screen_name' on 'class org.ScreenCreation: Error setting expression 'Screen_name' with value ['kjn', ]

That error means you are missing the Setter for your attribute in the Action.

if the attribute is `Screen_name`, the setter should be

```java
public void setScreen_name(){}
```

but that's a really wrong syntax for a variable, try avoiding underscores and especially capitalized first letter by usign camelCase, eg `screenName`:

```java
private String screeName;

public void setScreenName(){...}
```